# How to CALL Procedure inside WITH clause and use RETURNING in PROCEDURE CALL

Tags: postgresql, cte

I have query as shown below.

I get the id from one table after inserting value in it,the id in "table1" is set as SERIAL I want the id from another table which is "table2", I use a Procedure to INSERT in "table2".

When I CALL a procedure inside WITH clause I get error **ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CALL"**

And too I want to call the id from "refernce1" inside the CALL PROCEDURE.

Please, please help me with it.

I am using PostgreSQL

```
WITH "refernce1" AS(
INSERT INTO schema."table1" ("row1","row2") VALUES ('value1','value1') 
RETURNING "id" AS id
),
"refernce2" AS(
CALL schema."PROCEDURE_NAME"(
'value1',
'value2', 
 **SELECT id FROM "refernce1"**
 ) RETURNING "id" AS location_id
 )
```

If you want the original query then:

```
WITH "enquiry_id" AS(
INSERT INTO enquiry."mainEnquiry" ("remarks","status") VALUES ('Hello',1) RETURNING "id" AS enquiry_id
),
"location" AS(
CALL enquiry."INSERT_LOCATION"(
    'India', 
    'Maharashtra', 
    'Mumbai', 
    'Malad', 
     SELECT enquiry_id FROM "enquiry_id", 
    '524 and 525 IVConsultancy'
) RETURNING "id" AS location_id
)
INSERT INTO enquiry."contactClient"("enquiry_id","contactName","contactPerson","emailId","contactNumber","location")
(
SELECT enquiry_id,'Purav','Purav','purav.learner@gmail.com','7304036480',SELECT location_id FROM "location" FROM "enquiry_id"
)
```

Comment: You can't call a procedure as part of another statement. If you really need that (which is a rather strange thing to do) use a function, not a procedure. What exactly is that procedure doing?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: So should I make a function instead of procedure and call it

Comment: Yes, procedures aren't meant to return anything. The function should return whatever you need inside the CTE. But this still sounds like a really strange setup you have there

Comment: So what should I do to improve it, please if possible for you help me in it.

Comment: I am a beginner so I don't know a lot much how to design database and manage it...